# Binding MongoDB to IPv6

Tags: mongodb, ipv6

All MongoDB programs and processes disable IPv6 support by default, I already try bellow command to binding with IPv6 but it is not working:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/mongoDB --ipv6 --bind_ip 2004:c000:302::2
```

How can i enable IPv6 in MongoDB? and how can i bind MongoDB to IPv6?

Comment: are you sure that IP is correct?

Comment: @malyy yes. i use it for postgres and it works

Comment: If you use IPv6 and use the <address>:<port> format, you must enclose the portion of an address and port combination in brackets (e.g. [<address>]), see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/

Comment: @Jaco you mean i should use it like this  --bind_ip 2004:c000:302::2:27017 ?

Comment: You need to use [2004:c000:302::2] or  [2004:c000:302::2]:[27017]

Comment: @Jaco i use   mongod --dbpath ~/mongoDB --ipv6 --bind_ip [2004:c000:302::2]   But it doesn't work. error:  getaddrinfo("[2004:c000:302::2]:[27017]") failed: Name or service not known

Comment: Does it work without the port ? It is not clear from the documentation, but apparently the port does not need square brackets, so it needs to be either `[2004:c000:302::2]` or `[2004:c000:302::2]:27017`

Comment: @jaco thanks a lot for helping me. but at the end i solve it by remove --bind_ip and it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the end enable IPv6 by removing --bind_ip, like this:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/mongoDB --ipv6
```

Comment: but it doesn't solve the problem. i can't still set constrain on IPs.

Answer (score 0):

As of v3.0 --ipv6 is not required, it supports ipv6 by default, and to bind to a specific address you specifiy the address with `net.bindIp` in the config file, for example:

```
  bindIp: 2004:c000:302::2,192.168.0.1
```

Just tested this on a linux box (ubuntu 16), with mongodb v3.4 (community):

`$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:27017       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16440/mongod
tcp6       0      0 2004:c000:302::2:27017  :::*                    LISTEN      16440/mongod
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1385/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1385/sshd
$`

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration specifies the required settings which worked for me:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/

Basically the changes i did were to specify the following in "--config" file

```
bind_ip = 0::0  # I prefer this over :: as it sometimes causes parsing errors
ipv6 = true
```

[This is 2.4 format, new YAML format also has similar settings: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/